# Fullpage doesn't save correctly in source code in tinymce

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have a problem while saving a fullpage setting, before saving I added some code in source code, after saving it deletes its.

While saving the page, I just use the source code page with open

Any idea can be appreciate?

Comment: Are you trying to include some scripts inside editor ?

Comment: normal text, it doesn't work when source code is on, if I toogle editor it is working fine

Comment: check the plugin manager search for tiny mce, make sure setting have no prohibited text,check advanced option too.

Comment: Yes, I have checked in the plugin manager however it is not working. In joomla! 3.2 article manager it is working but with other any 3rd party components are not working

Comment: Editor Plugin have many options to include in any other components , so 3rd party plugin uses some limited options thats is the reason bcoz it fine for Joomla articles. check extension editor including section

Comment: Jose, thank you! I checked the location of code used in article manager they used `<?php echo $this->form->getField('articletext')->save(); ?>` inside the javascript, it is used to save the process. However they used in default form XML layout, for some reasons I am using manually used code for editor

Comment: I would not recommend using a wysiwyg if you are trying to insert text. Turn your personal editor settings to "none."  Also make sure your input filterng is set to raw in global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Below script used to save the "toogle/source code" editor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
{
    if (task == 'article.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('item-form')))
    {
        **<?php echo $this->form->getField('articletext')->save(); ?>**

        Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('item-form'));
    }
}
```